# How do I create this animation transition?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, animator

I'm working with a 3D avatar and it's my first time working with animations. I have already done one which goes from the idle animation to another animation. It does the transition when the value of a slidebar is below 40, here is the code:

```
public Slider barraAlimento;
void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}
void Update()
{
    if (barraAlimento.value <= 40)
    {
        anim.SetBool("IrHambriento", true);
    }
    else
    {
        anim.SetBool("IrHambriento", false);
    }
}
```

This works correctly, but my problem is that now I want to do another transition. When I click a button, the value of the slidebar increases (that's how is triggered the previous animation), so I want a transition between the previous animation and the new one when the button is pressed. I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
 public Button botonManzana;
 void Start()
 {
     anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
     botonManzana.onClick.AddListener(ButtonManzanaClicked);
 }
 void ButtonManzanaClicked()
 {
     anim.SetBool("IrComiendo", true);
     anim.SetBool("IrComiendo", false);
 }
```

The boxes and arrows are like this, if that's useful information.

[Animation transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhZlV.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for a *trigger* rather than a bool.

Change the bool value in your animator from Boolean to Trigger and change your code to...

```
void ButtonManzanaClicked() 
{
    anim.SetTrigger("IrComiendo");
}
```

This will make a transition happen every time you "Trigger" the trigger, like a one time thing, that doesn't require any boolean true -> false for resetting like you're attempting in this code.

The reason your code isn't working, I believe, is because you're re-setting it back to `false` in the same frame, and I think the animation system will look at the values at the end of each code frame, so to speak.

Comment: I tried that, but when it has to do the first animation (Hambriento) it only does this new one (Comiendo), and it doesn't return to the previous animation.

Answer (score 0):

this is probably happening because in:

```
void ButtonManzanaClicked()
{
    anim.SetBool("IrComiendo", true);
    anim.SetBool("IrComiendo", false);
}
```

you are setting it to false right after you set it to true.

Try putting only `anim.SetBool("IrComiendo", true);` in the button click event, and `anim.SetBool("IrComiendo", false);` only when you want it to go back to the "Hambriento" animation

EDIT:
try doing this:

change "IrComiendo" to trigger (just to not need to change its value to false)
OBS: use `anim.SetTrigger("IrComiendo");` to call it

set the connections as in the image:
[image]

* connection not necessary if its impossible that the value of the slider still smaller than 40 after the button is clicked

** put this connection if you want it to go to Comiendo even if it isnt hambriento

OBS: in the button method you just need change the value of the slider and call "IrComiendo"

hope it helped

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work. I have tried to only put anim.SetBool("IrComiendo", true); in the button click event to check if that part works, but it doesn't do the animation when I click the button. Instead, the first time there is a transition between the idle animation and the "Hambriento" animation, but it doesn't go to "Comiendo" animation. The second time, it goes from idle animation to "Comiendo" animation and stops there, not returning to any animation.

Comment: Is the value of IrComiendo true the first time you click the button? Is the condition of the transition from Hambriento to Comiendo set as IrComiendo = true?

Comment: Yes, it is set as true in the condition. I have tried to write `anim.SetBool("IrComiendo", false);` at the beginning of Start() method, and now it goes to Comiendo animation the first time instead of the second (without pressing the button).

Comment: so you want it to go to Hambriento the first time you click the button and to Comiendo the second time you click the button, right? If thats it, in the button method  you can get the state of "IrHambriento" using anim.GetBool("IrHambriento") and do anim.SetBool("IrComiendo", true); if it is true.

Comment: No, sorry, that's not it. Every time the value of a slider (which decreases over time) is <=40, the avatar goes from Idle Animation to Hambriento. But in order to increase that value, I have to click a button, so when it is in Hambriento I want it to go to Comiendo animation when presising the button, and now that the value is >40 it has to return to Idle Animation.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't answer before. I don't know what is happening but it still doesn't work.